# Boolean Modifier Issues (Engraving text on to a face)

Tags: modeling, mesh

So, what I am trying to do is engrave some numbers in to the side of a dice.

I have been following the tutorials that I can find which includes;

1) Converting my text objects in to a mesh
2) Applying the boolean to the dice and selecting the object.

Either 1 of 2 things happen, either the dice disappears, or nothing 'seamlessly' happens.

Can anyone shed some light on what basic step I may be missing?[image]
[image]

Thank you again for your time!

Comment: You can manually **join** those indices mesh into one object and do the boolean again. It may help a little bit.

Comment: this worked okay for me. https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/387475783838466051/596601844961247272/unknown.png

Answer (score 2):

You actually did what you wanted in the second picture, the old Text mesh is only still visible... you could delete it or hide it to see the results. Further notes on general good practice: After following Hikariztw's suggestion to join the text objects together first, which makes life way easier, you could try changing the solver to "Carve"... (in the modifier) takes a bit longer but is more accurate and less buggy most of the time. Also you could try to recalculate normals in edit mode for both objects (ctrl+N) –