# Boolean modifier not working, tried solutions suggested in similar articles

Tags: modifiers

I have recently tried to make vice and when using the boolean modifier to create holes for screws, it didn't work. I selected the main body, added modifier and chose my cylinder that was supposed to make the screw hole. Since I needed the "difference" setting, I selected it and all that happened was that the cylinder just stayed there and didn't create the hole I needed. I have checked youtube tutorials, questions and answers on this topic on this website and tried the solutions people suggested, yet nothing worked. Could someone help me solve this problem and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Notes: I'm using blender 2.79b

[image: Screenshot of blender]

Comment: Maybe the same Problem as here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144532/boolean-modifier-issues-engraving-text-on-to-a-face/144538#144538

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: **SOLVED**
As Robert suggested, it was the same problem that was described in the article he linked, so big thanks to him for helping me out.